# Concrete example of the Inverse Function Theorem

Tags: real-analysis

I'm preparing for my upcoming final, and I got stuck with one of the problems we got in order to prepare:

> > Let $F: \mathbb{R}^5 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be a $C^1$ function such that $F(0)=(3,1,1)$. such that 
> >     $DF(0) = \begin{bmatrix} 
> > 1 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 1 \\
> > 1 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
> > 1 & 0 & 1 & 3 & 1 \\
> > \end{bmatrix}$

Part a) was to show that there existed an open set of $y=(x_2,x_3,x_5)$ near $(0,0)$ such that $y$ could be solved in terms of $x=(x_1,x_4)$. This basically just is showing that $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 2 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}$ is invertible, and thus the Implicit Function Theorem can be applied.

Now, part b) is where I have trouble with.  It asks:

> > If $y=(x_2(x_1,x_4),x_3(x_1,x_4),x_5(x_1,x_4))$, compute $\frac{\partial x_3}{\partial x_4}$.

My idea was to use the Chain Rule: namely, $$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_4} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x_3}\frac{\partial x_3}{\partial x_4}$$ but the derivatives involved aren't square matrices, so I'm not sure what I should be doing. Could anyone steer me into the right direction?